# How to show just an element from json file after ajax calling

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this JSON file:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Mario",
    "cognome": "Rossi",
    "CF": "MROS4343242",
    "eta": "45",
    "sesso": "Uomo",
},{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Simon",
    "cognome": "Jason",
    "CF": "JSOS4343242",
    "eta": "30",
    "sesso": "Uomo",
}]
```

I did an ajax calling to print a little table with just "name" and "cognome", then I would build a button to show entire details of every user..so this is what I see now:

```
Mario | Rossi | "Button to see Mario'details"
Simon | Jason | "Button to see Simon'details"
```

but how can I do that with jquery/ajax?

This is the code now:

```
function getData()  {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data/persona1.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:showData,
    error: function() {
        // richiesta fallita
        alert("ERRORE!");
    }
});
}


function showData(pdata) 
var container = $('#tableContainer tbody');

container.append(
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + pdata.nome + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + pdata.cognome + '</td>' +
    '<td><a href="#modalContainer" rel="modal:open" onclick="getDetails()">Details</a></td></tr>' +
    '</tr>'
);
```

}

Comment: I'm confused - you say you're making an AJAX request, then ask how you do it with AJAX. It's not clear what you're asking. Also, what is your current code?

Comment: I did an ajax request to print "name" and "cognome", then how can I do to show details of each user? I don't know if i need to do another ajax request or if I can do that in another way..

Comment: You shouldn't need another AJAX request if you have all the required information in the first one. Can you please edit your question to include the code you've got so far

Comment: Ok, I included the code

Answer (score 0):

You could store all the data for every user in hidden vars, and once you click the button you could load the data for that user.You wouldn't need an ajax call, it hasn't sense because you don't need go to the server to load or threat the data.

Would be different if you would need load more info on the server than the you have on your json file. Then you only would need store that data to load it on the server and after on your page.

Your qüestion it's not much clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a constructor for the person object and store each person as a variable in a table. Then you would be able to use each person's information per your liking and definitely won't need another ajax call. A small example of what I am suggesting: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsjzLhfx/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var JSONTable = [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Mario",
        "cognome": "Rossi",
        "CF": "MROS4343242",
        "eta": "45",
        "sesso": "Uomo",
    },{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Simon",
        "cognome": "Jason",
        "CF": "JSOS4343242",
        "eta": "30",
        "sesso": "Uomo",
    }];

    function personData(id,name,cognome,CF,eta,sesso){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
      this.cognome = cognome;
      this.CF = CF;
      this.eta = eta;
      this.sesso = sesso;
    }

    function parseData(json){
      var parsedTable = new Array();

      for (var i=0; i<json.length;i++){
        parsedTable[i] = new personData(json[i].id, json[i].name, json[i].cognome,json[i].CF,json[i].eta, json[i].sesso);  
        }
        for (var i=0; i<parsedTable.length;i++){
            console.log(parsedTable[i]);
        var htmlCode = '<tr><td>' + parsedTable[i].name +       '</td><td>' + parsedTable[i].cognome + '</td><td><button id="clickInfo' + i + '" >Click me</button></td></tr>'
        var moreInfo = "CF:" + parsedTable[i].CF + " Eta:" + parsedTable[i].eta + " Sesso:" + parsedTable[i].sesso;

        $(htmlCode).appendTo("#personInfo");

        $("#clickInfo"+i).on('click',function(){
        alert(moreInfo);
        });
        }

    }

    parseData(JSONTable);

    });`
```

Sorry for the design, it's just to give you a small idea of how you can make use of the variables you have already stored.