# Print all user's details from json file (jquery/ajax)

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have this json file:

```
[{
"id": "1",
"nome": "Mario",
"cognome": "Rossi",
"CF": "MROS4343242",
"eta": "45",
"sesso": "Uomo",
"indirizzo": "Via Rossi 8",
"luogo": "Milano",
"provincia": "Milano",
"citta": "Milano",
"comune": "Milano"
},
{
"id": "2",
"nome": "jason",
"cognome": "marion",
"CF": "MROS4343242",
"eta": "35",
"sesso": "Uomo",
"indirizzo": "Via Prova 71",
"luogo": "Bologna",
"provincia": "Bologna",
"citta": "Milano",
"comune": "Milano"
}]
```

I have already done an ajax request to print in a html file just "nome" and "cognome":

```
function getData()  {
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data/persona1.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:showData,
    error: function() {
        // richiesta fallita
        alert("ERRORE!");
    }
});
}

function showData(pdata) {
var container = $('#tableContainer tbody');
container.html(
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + pdata.nome + '</td>' +
    '<td>' + pdata.cognome + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
);
}
```

Now I would build a link/button next to "cognome" to show all user's details like this:

```
Mario | Rossi | "Button to show Mario Rossi'details"
Jason | Marion | "Button to show Jason Marion'details"
```

How can I print the details? I need to do another ajax request to extract data (again) from json file?

Comment: Try this: `success: function(data) { showData(data) }`

Comment: This seems exactly the same as your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956414/how-to-show-just-an-element-from-json-file-after-ajax-calling). If you have an issue with the answers left there, please leave a comment on them.

Comment: that question was confused and incomplete, no one understood the question I did. I'd delete my previous question

Answer (score 0):

you can to combine the above into one so that you can get the data from ajax call into a success callback function:

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'data/persona1.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(pdata) {
      var container = $('#tableContainer tbody');
      container.html(
        '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + pdata.nome + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + pdata.cognome + '</td>' +
        '</tr>' +
      );
    },
    error: function() {
      // richiesta fallita
      alert("ERROR!");
    },
  });
}
```

you can set display:none on anything that you'd like to be hidden and then use a button to show it, like this:

```
'<td style="display:none" class="mydata' + pdata.Id + '">' + pdata.nome + '</td>'
```

using the id on all items will allow you to create a button that targets all items with the same id as class:

```
'<td><input type="button" class="mydata' + pdata.Id + '" onclick="showItems(' + pdata.Id + ')" value="show details">'
```

and then have a functions that show all the details:

```
function showItems(itemId) {
    $('.mydata'+itemId).show();
}
```

Comment: Why combine? Much more testable if separate - if the OP cares about tests that is

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - he mentioned that he's not getting the data through.